# Problems 3.2, I. Martin Isaacs' Algebra

Tags: group-theory

> Let $Q_8$ be Quarternion. Show that $G/Z(G)$ can never be isomorphic
>   to $Q_8$.  Here is $Z(G)$ denote the center of $G$.
>
> Hint (in the book) : If $G/Z(G)$ isomorphic to $Q_8$, show that $G$ has
>   two abelian subgroups of index $2$.

I couldn’t find a reason why $G$ should have two abelian subgroups. Even if I found the two subgroups, I don’t understand how it is related to the problem itself.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas you can use:

- If $H/Z(H)$ is cyclic, then $H$ is abelian.
- If you have two distinct abelian subgroups $A$ and $B$ of index $2$, then $G = AB$ and $A \cap B$ is central.

Use the first one to find the two abelian subgroups of index $2$, and the second one to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I can prove the hint - not sure about the original problem :

If $G/Z(G) \cong Q_8$, then $G/Z(G)$ has two cyclic subgroups $\overline{H}, \overline{K}$ of index 2 (corresponding to $\langle i \rangle$ and $\langle j \rangle$ in $Q_8$). Choose subgroups $H, K < G$ which correspond to $\overline{H}$ and $\overline{K}$ in the quotient.

Now, $Z(H) \supset Z(G)$, so
$$
H/Z(H) \cong \frac{H/Z(G)}{Z(H)/Z(G)}
$$
and so $H/Z(H)$ is cyclic, and so $H$ is abelian. Similarly, $K$ is abelian.